# SQLite/SpatiaLite error: no such function: ImportGeoJSON

Tags: geojson, import, spatialite, database, sqlite

I'm inside a bash script trying to import a GeoJSON  file into a SQLite DB.
I tried both ...

```
SPATIALITE_SECURITY=relaxed sqlite3 'db.sqlite' "SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')" "SELECT ImportGeoJSON('file.geojson', 'osmgeojson')"
```

... and ...

```
export SPATIALITE_SECURITY=relaxed
sqlite3 'db.sqlite' "SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')" "SELECT ImportGeoJSON('file.geojson', 'osmgeojson')"
```

... but either way I get this error:

```
Error: no such function: ImportGeoJSON
```

Note that in both cases I did set SPATIALITE_SECURITY=relaxed as the docs said ( http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html ).

I'm sure that SpatiaLite is loaded correctly, as it throws no error and this command ...

```
SPATIALITE_SECURITY=relaxed sqlite3 'db.sqlite' "SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')" "SELECT spatialite_version()"
```

... returns ...

```
4.3.0a
```

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Spatialite's timeline](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/timeline?advm=0&n=50&ss=m&b=2019-01-16) I realised that ImportGeoJSON() was introduced after 5.0.0-beta0 so obviously it wasn't supported by the 4.3.0a I had on my system.

I have updated Spatialite to 5.0.1 (actually [I had to upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04 to do that without compiling it](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spatialite)) and now the function is recognised.

Comment: Spatialite 5.0.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 does not recognise the function. Possibly something else missing.